# Analyze core-dumps created while running wireshark on linux

Tags: wireshark

I am running wireshark build on linux. I get a crash,while doing some activities. A core dump is also being generated. But,when i give the following command
gdb ./wireshark core.
It says,file format not recognized. Also,when i do a 
cat on "./wireshark",it seems to be some kind of script.
so how to analyze core dumps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the script to see what is the actual wireshark binary being run.

gdb is good for coredump analysis.

Comment: ok,i will try that. do you know where the binary can be located?

Answer (score 0):

> when i do a cat on "./wireshark",it seems to be some kind of script.

Probably because you've built Wireshark from source in that directory, in which case it *is* a script (generated by [libtool](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/) as [a wrapper script](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Wrapper-executables)).

What you need to do, instead of

```
gdb ./wireshark core`
```

is

```
./libtool --mode=execute gdb ./wireshark core
```

which will do the right magic to run GDB on the actual executable rather than on the script (and to pass it the right magic to find the shared libraries in your build directory).